# Add a class to a list item in a generated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

For some reason, this is not making any sense to me. I am trying to create a list of numbers from 1 to `num`, with any numbers that match a number in an array receiving a special class name. Code below:

#### HTML

```
<ul id="bb"></ul>
```

#### JS

```
var arr = ['2', '6', '10'];
var num = 25;
var i = 0;
var li = '';

while (i <= num) {
    for (x in arr) {
        if (i === parseInt(arr[x], 10)) {
            li += '<li class="jj">'+ i +'</li>';
        } else {
            $('#bb').append('<li>'+ i +'</li>');
        }
    }
    //li += '<li>'+ i +'</li>';
    $('#bb').html(li);
    i++;
}
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are overriding the html

```js
var arr = ['2', '6', '10'];
var num = 25;
var i = 0;
var li = '';

while (i <= num) {
  //use Array.indexOf() to check whether array contains the value, the `+ ''` is used to convert `i` value to a string since the array contains string values
  if (arr.indexOf(i + '') > -1) {
    li += '<li class="jj">' + i + '</li>';
  } else {
    li += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
  }
  i++;
}

//set the content of the ul at the end of the loop since `li` will have all the required html
$('#bb').html(li);
```

```css
.jj {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="bb"></ul>
```